# VBScript - Run from variable network path

Tags: variables, vbscript, path

I'm trying to modify part of a script so that it can run from any of our DP's. Here is the current code section:

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run("""\\SERVER\SHARE\FOLDER\FOLDER2\FOLDER3\INSTALL_ME.exe""")
Set objShell = Nothing
```

This works but I don't want it to run only from this location but from what ever DP it is being executed from. The only part of the path that would change would be the SERVER name. The SHARE and FOLDER paths would be constant. Is there a wildcard or another method I can use for the SERVER name?

I've been researching using something like app.path but haven't been successful finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the path of the script using this portion of code:

```
szPath = Left(WScript.ScriptFullName, Len(WScript.ScriptFullName) - Len(WScript.ScriptName))
```